# Saving a TypeScript array that is part of an Array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array declared with:

```
public chartData: Array<any> = [];
```

I set the data in the form of a dictionary like this:

```
this.chartData = [{ data: [1, 2, 3, 5], label: 'Default Chart' }];
```

I'm new to TypeScript - how would you go about saving the 'data' portion of 'chartData'? I'm trying to update this.chartData but only the 'label' portion. My idea is to save the 'data' part of chartData and set this.chartData again but with a new label like this:

```
var savedChartData = //saved 'data' portion of chartData
this.chartData = [{ savedChartData, label: 'New Label' }];
```

Comment: you can't just modify chartData[0].label?

Comment: That's TypeScript, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.chartData[0].data
```

You need to get the first object of the array, and get the data field of that.

Why not just use an object?

Comment: I'm using a package called ng2-charts - the data needs to be formatted in that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows;

```
this.chartData = [{ data: [1, 2, 3, 5], label: 'Default Chart' }];
this.chartData[0].label = 'New Label';
```

And you can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp), and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).